Nested saving of purrr mapping objects in R
I think I have run into a very specific "idiosyncrasy" with purrr environmental variables that I do not understand.
GOAL: From a function, to call save or saveRDS of variables in the parent frame, given we know the variable names and can specify them in a character vector.
PROBLEM: When the function is inside purrr::map, it doesn't work.
EXAMPLE:
fun <- function() {save(list = ".x", file = "/home/user/file.rdata")}
purrr::map(.x = list(iris), .f = ~fun())
error message in attached photo error message when nested in purrr
EXPECTED OUTPUT:
the function saves iris to file
EDIT: i've also tried specifying every frame possible for save. there is only one .x but does not have the value of iris.
I know I am getting the correct variable and I am in the correct environment, but it feels as though .x is "unevaluated" but get doesn't work either. If anyone knows a way around this and why this behaviour exists that would be fantastic

By the way, instead of ~fun() you can directly use fun. No need for the lambda.

you can use rlang::caller_env() but you almost certainly shouldnt. What follows is terrible, and there is almost certainly a better way to save your data out, but you get what you asked for ...
fun <- function(){
  what_i_got <- get(".x",envir=rlang::caller_env())
  # save it out or what have you
}
purrr::map(.x = list(iris), .f = ~fun())


what is normally done
fun <- function(.x){
  what_i_got <-.x
  # save it out or what have you
}
purrr::map(.x = list(iris), .f = fun)


I am curious can you elaborate on why you caution against this approach? Is there a scenario where you can overwrite things unintentionally in the calling environment?

its more for your own sanity; there is simply no benefit to doing it in this abstract way, when it can be done directly. with pure function. passing params. its less typing also... (minor benefit). The only reason to do it this bizarre way is to obfuscate what one is doing; to tax the readers mental ability....

my apologies for the question potentially looking like i'm trying to make a square wheel out of a round one - my actual use case is indeed much more sophisticated than the example given, but my probems really do boil down to this issue of trying to get an object by name from the calling environment

".x" is not found within fun() because you're not passing any data to it. Try adding an argument:
fun <- function(x) {
  save(list = "x", file = "/home/user/file.rdata")
  }

purrr::map(.x = list(iris), .f = ~fun(.x))

You can also just do: save(x, ...)

is there any way to do this without having to change the way the function is called? such as by trying to look back to parent frames from inside the nested function call (which i couldnt make work)

Not the way you've specified your function.

why is that? i would have thought that you can work around it if in the function you call get or similar before you call save, together with a suitable choice of negative integer for sys.frame
